# Do the Request filters get run from BasicAppHost?

Tags: servicestack

I know that the services get wired-up by instantiating the BasicAppHost, and the IoC by using the ConfigureContainer property, but where is the right place to add the filters? The test in question never fire the global filter:

```
[TestFixture]
public class IntegrationTests
{
    private readonly ServiceStackHost _appHost;

    public IntegrationTests()
    {
        _appHost = new BasicAppHost(typeof(MyServices).Assembly)
        {
            ConfigureContainer = container =>
            {
                //
            }
        };
        _appHost.Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
        _appHost.Config = new HostConfig { DebugMode = true };
        _appHost.GlobalRequestFilters.Add(ITenantRequestFilter);
       _appHost.Init();
    }

    private void ITenantRequestFilter(IRequest req, IResponse res, object dto)
    {
        var forTennant = dto as IForTenant;
        if (forTennant != null)
            RequestContext.Instance.Items.Add("TenantId", forTennant.TenantId);
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void TestFixtureTearDown()
    {
        _appHost.Dispose();   
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanInvokeHelloServiceRequest()
    {
        var service = _appHost.Container.Resolve<MyServices>();

        var response = (HelloResponse)service.Any(new Hello { Name = "World" });

        Assert.That(response.Result, Is.EqualTo("Hello, World!"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanInvokeFooServiceRequest()
    {
        var service = _appHost.Container.Resolve<MyServices>();

        var lead = new Lead
        {
            TenantId = "200"
        };

        var response = service.Post(lead); //Does not fire filter.
    }
}
```

ServiceStack is set at 4.0.40

**Updated**
After perusing the ServiceStack tests (which I highly recommend BTW) I came across a few example of the AppHost being used AND tested. It looks like the "ConfigureAppHost" property is the right place to configure the filters, e.g.

```
ConfigureAppHost = host =>
    {
        host.Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
        host.GlobalRequestFilters.Add(ITenantRequestFilter);
    },
ConfigureContainer = container =>
    {
    }
```

**Updated1**
And they still don't fire.

**Updated2**

After a bit of trial and error I think it's safe to say that NO, the filters are not hooked up while using the BasicAppHost. What I have done to solve my problem was to switch these tests to use a class that inherits from AppSelfHostBase, and use the c# servicestack clients to invoke the methods on my service. THIS does cause the global filters to be executed.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the Request and Response filters only fire for Integration Tests where the HTTP Request is executed through the [HTTP Request Pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations). If you need to test the full request pipeline you'd need to use a Self-Hosting Integration test.

Calling a method on a Service just does that, i.e. it's literally just making a C# method call on a autowired Service - there's no intermediate proxy magic intercepting the call in between.